# Подскажите что не так

Tags: c#

У меня работающий англо-русский словарь. Слова и перевод берет с присоединенной БД. При попытке добавить новые значения или отредактировать старые, путем юзания кнопок "+" и "х" на стандартной панели управления (она создалась автоматически, я в ней ничего не менял) иногда вылетает такое (см. скрин), при этом данные естественно не сохраняются. Один человек посоветовал скачать Nuget, скачать либу MySql и дальше плясать с бубном.

Как можно убрать/исправить эту ошибку не переделывая наново все?

Скрин[image: Скрин места в коде где был пойман баг, на этапе дебагаC#]

Comment: А иногда изменения сохраняются? Не совсем понятно, стабильно ли сыплется.

Comment: Совершенно верно, когда этой ошибки нет - изменения сохраняются...
"...Не совсем понятно, стабильно ли сыплется...."  - вообще не понял, о чем Вы.. =(

Comment: Добавьте текст ошибки в название вопроса, чтобы другие могли его найти.

Comment: Ваш вопрос подобен следующему: "Угадайте, как у меня все сделано, и скажите, что изменить, чтобы не было этой ошибки."  Сообщение достаточно определенно говорит о проблеме с `tableAdapterManager.UpdateCommand` - весьма вероятно, ee (`UpdateCommand`) отсутствии.

Comment: Функция "Обновить таблицу..." - недоступна, выбор неактивен, поле id добавил, запрет на ввод пустых строк имеется. В источнике данных на кнопку обновить ткнул.

Answer (score 1):

Явно глюк с базой данных. Варианты решения:

1. Перейти в дизайнер Dataset'а (Меню "Data" - "show data sources" - "Edit dataset with designer". В контекстном меню адаптера выбрать "Configure" - "Advanced options". Убедиться, что выбрано "Refresh the data table", нажать OK и Finish.
2. В БД отсутствует первичный ключ или он содержит некорректные данные (например, если был импорт из Access). Проверьте таблицу, столбцы ключей, уникальность данных в них, отсутствие нулевых значений.

Comment: БД сделана в Acces. Там одна таблица с полями En и Ru. Id я не делал. Подскажите мне проч

Comment: Посмотрел то что Вы сказали. Возможность "Обновить таблицу после выполнения запросов" - неактивна. Это из за отсутствия id?
  Убрал возможность вводить в БД пустые поля. Проблема осталась. Касательно текста ошибки - добавлю, обязательно.

Comment: Рекомендую создать в таблице первичный ключ.

Comment: создал, все то же. Может там надо как то дать понять студии что там первичный ключ появился?

Comment: появилась новая ошибка, при удалении теперь и при редактировании. Подскажите кто нибудь как скрин в комменты скинуть?

Comment: @Atos в комментарий никак - залейте на любой файловый сервер и сбросьте в комментарий прямую ссылку на изображение **или** обновите Ваш вопрос, добавив к нему скриншоты новой ошибки и подробности ошибки(так будет правильнее).

Comment: спасибо проблема решена уже :)